# What does the first line mean in the code to 'find the difference between the sum of odd and even position digits.(max 100 digits)'

Tags: python

```
num = [int(d) for d in str(input("Enter the number:"))]

even,odd = 0,0
for i in range(0,len(num)):
    if i % 2 ==0:
        even = even + num[i]
    else:
        odd = odd + num[i]

print(abs(odd-even))
```

> What does the first line mean for taking strings as input?

Comment: It means that the author used Python 2.

Comment: It's a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
num = [int(d) for d in str(input("Enter the number:"))]
```

will error out if anything but digits are entered.  If only digits are entered, then they end up being individual integer entries in `num`.  For example, for the input `124`, the resulting value of `num` will be `[1, 2, 4]`.  The code will then go on to process each of those single digit numeric values.

BTW, the call to `str()` is redundant, as `input` already returns a string value.

Comment: @Abhi - Greetings.  I am wondering if my answer to your question was helpful.  Did it answer your question?  If so, I encourage you to upvote it and/or accept it as the correct answer via the checkmark button.  Note that you get points for accepting an answer.